# Endless while loop and old removed code (popup)... well "popping up."

Tags: python, jython, sikuli-ide, sikuli-x

I'm struggling to troubleshoot a strange problem I've been having since starting to use Sikuli over multiple projects. I've been using the IDE and later tried to branch out due to having strange things happening with code. If I were to debug code earlier with popups, I can save the code, even restart my pc, even check the code in other text editors but the now non-existent popups (and old code) sometimes, well, pop up. In the end normally I end up ditching original files, and having to sometimes strangely comment out lines and re-add them one at a time (even though in the grand scale of things the end script was the same as before i did all that). I'm at a real loss for words.

It's making me struggle to differentiate between bad code and something going wrong elsewhere. Does anyone know what might cause this "phantom code"? Because I'm really at a loss.

And i would like advice as to what's going wrong with the while i < (inputvariable). I can't figure out what might be going wrong at all, am i over looking something?

I'm running all scripts through Sikuli IDE at the moment. I did want to learn how to write scripts and include sikuli hoping i could package it neatly but i couldn't seem to wrap my head around it.

For the while loop, where it's being compared to "SSLoops" i can't see why it's not breaking out of the loop when the criteria is met. (prints out above and beyond the number.)

I've had to do strange workarounds such as commenting out whole sections of code, trying to get it to work, and then slowly one by one reintroduce it till it matched the old script entirely. If I copied the script to a new file to make a cleaner copy, in hopes that if there is some sort of caching issue(?) it'd resolve, but I'd normally have to tinker around with it again.

```
BP = getBundlePath()
print(BP)
setBundlePath(BP + "\images")
BP2 = getBundlePath()
print(BP2)

# Regions
gameRegion = Region(230, 138, 1442, 875)
matchSpeedRegion = Region(1282, 920, 162, 91)
rewardRegion = Region()


def main():
    SSLoops = input("How many times would you like to run Super Smash?")
    SuperSmash(SSLoops)


def SuperSmash(SSLoops):
    print(SSLoops)
    i = 1
    while i < SSLoops:
        print(i)
        print(SSLoops)
        if exists("btnEnterSuperSmash.PNG"):
            click("btnEnterSuperSmash.PNG")
        while True:
            if exists("btnReward.png"):
                print("Completed! On to Rewards.")
                #selectRewards()
                break
            else:
                pass
            if matchSpeedRegion.exists("btnStart.png"):
                matchSpeedRegion.click("btnStart.png")
                matchSpeedRegion.wait("btnRetreat.png", 3600)
                if matchSpeedRegion.exists("btnSpeedUp.png"):
                    matchSpeedRegion.click("btnSpeedUp.png")
                    print("clicked x1")
                print("clicking retreat")
                matchSpeedRegion.click("btnRetreat.png")
                matchSpeedRegion.wait(Pattern("btnRetreat.png").similar(0.65), 3600)
                print("clicking okay")
                gameRegion.click("btnOK.png")
                wait(2)
                gameRegion.wait("btnOK.png", 3600)
                gameRegion.click("btnOK.png")
        print("Completed!")
        i = i + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I have been getting popups saying "hey" because i had a loop in while true btnRewards to run a function to say "hey" - this would have hopefully on on to pick a reward out of 5 images in the end. But after removing it, as i'm trying to trouble shoot the main loop, it still pops up.

The loop that compares the user input variable to i just keeps on increasing. The indentation looks okay to me? but i must be wrong? or is something else making it go wrong?

I've been making the program run on a folder so the pictures to break the loop are immediately up, so it should have theoretically ran the amount of times inputted without anything else (1). Any help is deeply appreciated.

```
====
1
1
1

[log] CLICK on L[889,656]@S(0) (568 msec)

Completed! On to Rewards.

Completed!
2
1

[log] CLICK on L[889,656]@S(0) (565 msec)

Completed! On to Rewards.

Completed!
3
1

[log] CLICK on L[889,656]@S(0) (584 msec)

Completed! On to Rewards.

Completed!
4
1
====
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem: `input()` returns a string like so "4"

you then compare it using
`while i < SSLoops:`

which is always `True` and hence the loop does not end.

using
`SSLoops = int(input("How many times would you like to run Super Smash?"))` will solve your problem.

Be aware: this will crash if the given input cannot be converted to an integer value.

Suggestion: debug prints should look like so:
print "SSLoops =", SSLoops

so the output is better readable.

RaiMan from SikuliX (greetings to your cat ;-)